# Помогите select → option оставить выбранным после action

Tags: php, post, form, html-select

Ломаю голову как оставить выбранным `option` в `select` после отправки формы через action `POST`.

Для инпутов это например:

```
value="<?=$_POST['title']?>"
```

(после отправки запроса возвращается то что ввел)

А вот для `select` не могу ничего придумать.

Вот пример:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
  <select name="opt">
    <option value="1" >Лена</option>    
    <option value="2" >Игорь</option>
    <option value="3" >Вася</option>    
    <option value="4" >Петя</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit"  value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Прописывать `selected` не вариант так как после отправки будет выбран тот `option` где прописан `selected`.

Записываю данные:

```
if (isset($_POST['opt']))   {$opt= $_POST['opt']; }

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (opt) VALUES ('$opt')
```

Помогите вернуть выбранный `option` после отправки формы.

Comment: Как у вас заполняется форма после отправки, каким образом, какие технологии вы используйте для этого, добавьте в вопрос этот код если он есть. В каком виде возвращаются данные после отправки, вы используйте jQuery, JavaScript или просто по средствам отправки вам генериться новая форма через РНР...

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: `mysql_query` лучше не использовать уже, его скоро перестанут использовать, переходите на `mysqli_query` , простите но, я не вижу того как вы заполняете форму после ее отправки, вообще судя по всему у вас идет авто заполнение самим браузером, и вам лучше использовать в данном случая AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <select name="opt">
      <option value="1"<?=isset($_POST) && $_POST["opt"]==1?" selected=\"selected\"":""?>>Лена</option>    
      <option value="2"<?=isset($_POST) && $_POST["opt"]==2?" selected=\"selected\"":""?>>Игорь</option>
      <option value="3"<?=isset($_POST) && $_POST["opt"]==3?" selected=\"selected\"":""?>>Вася</option>    
      <option value="4"<?=isset($_POST) && $_POST["opt"]==4?" selected=\"selected\"":""?>>Петя</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"  value="Отправить" />
</form>
```